# Targeting events in multiple similar groups of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, frontend

I need your help please.

I'm creating that component that regroups multiple selects and inputs from which I get the values to concatenate them in a string in a preview zone. This string is updated each time a change occurs in those inputs/selects.
It worked fine when I was working on one element, experimenting, styling it and stuff. Now I have to replicate it into possibly an infinite amount, so the script must work accordingly. The problem is that I'm useless when it comes to targeted selectorsn "this", "closest" and stuff. And I'm sure my logic is flawed when it comes to getting the values as you will see in the code I written.

I will share the JSFiddle, it will be easier to understand I think. If not, I will edit this post and share it directly.

Maybe I should declare a variable containing the targeting like [  var route = $(this).parent().closest() ] and use it all the other variables too ?

https://jsfiddle.net/HiD3f/8Lnowqvp/65/

```
<div class="container" id="settings-fr">

  <div class="group"> 
    <select class="day">
      <option value="1">Monday</option>
      <option value="2">Mon</option>
      <option value="3"> </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="group small-group"> 
    <input type="text" class="separator1">
  </div>

  <div class="group"> 
    <select class="date">
      <option value="1">October 29</option>
      <option value="2">Oct 29</option>
      <option value="3">10 29</option>
      <option value="1">29 October</option>
      <option value="2">29 Oct</option>
      <option value="3">29 10</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="group small-group"> 
    <input type="text" class="separator2">
  </div>

  <div class="group"> 
    <select class="year">
      <option value="1">2018</option>
      <option value="2">18</option>
      <option value="3"> </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="preview"> preview </div>

</div>


<div class="container" id="settings-us">

  <div class="group"> 
    <select class="day">
      <option value="1">Monday</option>
      <option value="2">Mon</option>
      <option value="3"> </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="group small-group"> 
    <input type="text" class="separator1">
  </div>

  <div class="group"> 
    <select class="date">
      <option value="1">October 29</option>
      <option value="2">Oct 29</option>
      <option value="3">10 29</option>
      <option value="1">29 October</option>
      <option value="2">29 Oct</option>
      <option value="3">29 10</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="group small-group"> 
    <input type="text" class="separator2">
  </div>

  <div class="group"> 
    <select class="year">
      <option value="1">2018</option>
      <option value="2">18</option>
      <option value="3"> </option>
    </select>
  </div>

   <div class="preview"> preview  </div>

</div>
```

and the script :

```
$('select, input').change(function() {

  let day = $(".day option:selected").text();
  let sep1 = $(".separator1").val();
  let date = $(".date option:selected").text();
  let sep2 = $(".separator2").val();
  let year = $(".year option:selected").text();

  let preview = day + sep1 + date + sep2 + year;

  let parent = $(".container");

  $(this).parent('.group').closest(".preview").empty().append(preview);

});
```

Please help me, I'm stuck. Thank you.

Comment: So it appears that your groupings are separated by a `.container` element.  So that would be the element by which all your contextual lookups should happen off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your logic to find children based off of the section they are in.

```js
$('select, input').change(function() {
  //find the container the changed element belongs to
  let $container = $(this).closest('.container');
  let day = $container.find('.day option:selected').text();
  let sept = $container.find('.separator1').val();
  
  //...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now, thanks to you and @front_end_dev :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your line

```
$(this).parent('.group').closest(".preview").empty().append(preview);
```

to

```
$(this).parents()
  .filter(function() {
    return (this.getAttribute('class') === 'container');
  }).find('.preview').text(preview);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works all good :)
Nice combo with @Taplar 's suggestion